# FBConnect : send some images on somebody's wall

Tags: iphone, upload, uiimage, fbconnect

I found out how to send some text on the user's wall, with the FBConnect API, on iphone.
I even found how to put an image already on the internet :

```
FBFeedDialog* dialog = [[[FBFeedDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.templateBundleId = 12345;
dialog.templateData = @"{\"image\":[{\"src\":\"http://sample.png\",\"href\":\"http://sample.com\"}] }";
[dialog show];
```

(see http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_for_iPhone)

But I can't figure out how to **upload** an **UIImage** from my iphone to the user's wall with FB Api.
Do I have, first, to upload the image on any website, then put its url in the **templateData** ?
Isn't there any simpler solution ?

Thanks.

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below function to upload the image, pass the UIImage as the parameter, it will work.

```
- (void)uploadPhoto:(UIImage *)uploadImage
{
    NSMutableDictionary *args = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [args setObject:uploadImage forKey:@"image"];    // 'images' is an array of 'UIImage' objects
    [args setObject:@"4865751097970555873" forKey:@"aid"];// this should be album id
    uploadPhotoRequest = [FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self];
    [uploadPhotoRequest call:@"photos.upload" params:args];

    NSLog(@"uploading image is successful");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code.
So you have two steps : first the upload, secondary the templateData.
Is there, on Facebook server, some places where you can put this kind of data ?

Comment: Comment says "images in an array...", but there is no variable "images" in the sample code.  Can you please edit?

Answer (score 0):

[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.photos.upload" params:params dataParam:(NSData*)img;

and pass params to nil . it will upload image to default album